# The global isn't working and didn't recognizing variable "text"?

Tags: python, tkinter, global

The global isn't working properly and it says that
it does not know what `text` is, even though it is declared `global`.

```
def nguess():
    answer = random.randint ( 1, 50 )

def check():
    global attempts
    attempts = 10
    global text
    attempts -= 1

    guess = int(e.get())
    if answer == guess:
        text.set("yay you gat it right")
        btnc.pack_forget()
    elif attempts == 0:
        text.set("you are out of attempts")
        btnc.pack_forget ()
    elif guess > answer:
        text.set("incorrect! you have "+ str(attempts) + "attempts remaining. Go higher")
    elif guess < answer:
        text.set("incorrect! you have "+ str(attempts) + "attempts remaining. Go lower")
    return


nw = tk.Toplevel(app)

nw.title("guess the number")
nw.geometry("500x150")
lable = Label(nw, text="guess the number between 1 - 50")
lable.pack()
e = Entry(nw, width = 40, borderwidth = 10)
e.pack()
btnc = Button(nw,text = "Check", command = check)
btnc.pack()
btnq = Button ( nw, text="Quit", command=nw.destroy )
btnq.pack()
text = StringVar()
text.set("you have ten attempts remaining ")
guess_attempts = Label (nw,textvariable = text)
guess_attempts.pack()
```

Comment: You have to initialize variable before trying to access to it's value.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @OlvinRoght I assume that the last section of the code isn't inside a function, and text is defined there, therefore no need to call anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the global variable `text` has set to something before `check` is called?

Comment: it actually is in a function

Comment: @swiflebot Then what you've posted is not representative of your actual code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: it was pasted differently but it is in nguess()

Comment: @khelwood You can't use a global variable without initializing it before because it'll point to something outer the `check`  function and won't find anything to get and raise an error

Comment: @BradFigueroa Yes, I'm aware that it would cause an error. That's why I asked, because the OP _is_ getting an error.

Comment: I got `NameError: name 'answer' is not defined` instead because `answer` is a local variable inside `nguess()`.  `text` should be accessible even without `global text` inside `check()`.  Also `attempts` will always be 9 inside `check()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's going on is you're trying to get a variable before initialize it i.e. in `check` function you're calling a `global text` variable so what it means is you're bringing whatever `text` variable stores in `global namespace`, but the problem is `text` variable isn't exist in `global namespace` yet because you've created after calling the `check` function. Below I show an example:

```
def test():
  global variable
  print(variable)

test()
variable = 'Hello'
```

This will raise an error because of what I just explained, so what you have to do is something like this(based on the example):

```
def test():
  global variable
  print(variable)


variable = 'Hello'
test()
```

In short, initialize the `text` variable before calling the `check` function which uses `global text`